# Log EF Core queries in console application with serilog

Tags: entity-framework-core, console-application, serilog

I have .NET 7 console app with DI and want to log queries to database with Serilog. So I created my Serilog logger and added it to DI:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();

services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(logger)
```

But how to configure `AppDbContext` to be able to write queries to my log?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wire you ILoggerFactory to the

DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(ILoggerFactory) Method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.useloggerfactory?view=efcore-7.0

Full example below.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Logging.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyCompany.MyProductLine.MyAppName.DomainDataLayer.EntityFramework.Contexts
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class MyAppNameDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public const string ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryIsNull = "ILoggerFactory is null";
        public const string ErrorMessageIHostEnvironmentIsNull = "IHostEnvironment is null";

        private readonly IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment; /* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0 */

        private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory; /* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0 */

        public MyAppNameDbContext(
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment,
            DbContextOptions<MyAppNameDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory ??
                                 throw new ArgumentNullException(
                                     ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryIsNull,
                                     (Exception)null);

            this.hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(
                ErrorMessageIHostEnvironmentIsNull,
                (Exception)null);
            /* note, the base-class checks for null for the DbContextOptions-"options" */

            if (this.hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                this.Database.EnsureCreated(); /* you do not need this, this is included as an example to a full working example */
            }
        }


        public DbSet<DepartmentEntity> Departments { get; set; } /* you do not need this, this is included as an example to a full working example */


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DepartmentMap()); /* you do not need this, this is included as an example to a full working example */

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

            // Allow null if you are using an IDesignTimeDbContextFactory
            if ((this.loggerFactory != null
                 && Debugger.IsAttached
                 && (this.hostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()))
                 )
            {
                //// Probably shouldn't log sql statements in production, so use "flags" (above if conditions) to only do it when a developer is involved.
                optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(this.loggerFactory);
            }
        }

}
```

Now the above is not going to magically "Just work".

You'll have to register this/your (Custom)DbContext with the

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-7.0

AddDbContext method.. using one of the "concrete" RDBMS options out there (Ms-Sql-Server, Postgres, etc, etc)

SIDE NOTE:

Outside and separate from the "wiring" above... in order to just ensure you have Serilog (or any "concrete" logger) working correctly....
You should put in some ".LogTrace", ".LogDebug", "LogInfo" calls....

Aka, make sure your those work... before wiring up the EF logger stuff.... just to make sure the "basics" are working..before thinking the EF wire up is not working. (#hindSightAdviceOnMyPart)